# Enabling Hot plug removable media. Virtualbox windows guest ubuntu host

Tags: 14.04, usb, virtualbox

So I have ubuntu 14.04 host with virtualbox installed. A windows 7 guest os on top of that. 
When I add a device filter for a specific device it works perfectly.

What I want to do is add a generic USB device filter that enables me to plug in a usb-stick and it wil be automatically available in the guest.

I have added the "all usb filter" (withouth specific info) but this does not work..

Does anybody have any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not stated directly in VirtualBox docs, filters with all criteria empty are ignored.

### Possible Workaround

To achieve behavior close to wanted you can create multiple filters - one for each USB port. But even this approach not gives exactly the same result - ports are not real USB connectors of your moherboard, but USB controller/hub ports.

To determine port number for each of USB socket insert some USB device and find it's port with command:

```
VBoxManage list usbhost
```

Also make sure your user is in `vboxusers` system group (remember logoff-logon after adding to user to group).

More about creating USB filters in VirtualBox manual:

> https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idp54668304

Comment: Ah that explains a lot! I think I got it working. The hard part was figuring out what port number to enter in that field. Thnx!!